# Django template not showing most of the page after using class-based view

Tags: python, django, templates, django-class-based-views

Here's the relevant view:

```
class board_lv(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'boardList.html'    
    context_object_name = 'notice_List'
    def get_queryset(self):
        self.Board = get_object_or_404(Board, name=self.args[0])
        if self.args[0] == 'all':           
            return Notice.objects.order_by('-posted_on')
        else:
            return Notice.objects.filter(board=self.Board)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(board_lv, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  
        context['c_board'] = self.Board;
```

And here is the html template:

```
<h1>/b/ {{c_board}}</h1>
<ul>
{% for n in notice_list %}
    <li>
    {% if not n.isText %} 
        <h2><a href="{{ n.content }}">{{ n.title }}</a></h2>(/b/{{n.board}})<br>    
    {% else %}
        <h2><a href= "{% url 'detail' n.id %}">{{ n.title }}</a></h2>(/b/{{n.board}})
        <p>{{ n.content|slice:":100" }}</p>     
    {% endif %}
        <a href="{% url 'detail' n.id %}">Comments</a>{{n.thumbs_up}}   
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

When I navigate to a board url which calls this view, all that shows is the first "/b/" in the top left corner. I'm guessing there's an issue with the contexts but I can't put my finger on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typo? - 'notice_List' in view, 'notice_list' in template.

Comment: ahh yeah I changed it out to a different name to see if it would work before I posted this, notice_List in the template produced the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually return the context from your  `get_context_data`  ! So change it like this

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(board_lv, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  
        context['c_board'] = self.Board;
        return context
```